# ZF2 - Deprecated: ServiceManagerAwareInterface is deprecated and will be removed in version 3.0, along with the ServiceManagerAwareInitializer

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, service-locator, zfcuser

I'm developing a project on ZF2 + Doctrine2. Also I'm using ZfcUser. My composer.json looks like:

```
    "php"                                       : ">=5.5",
    "zendframework/zendframework"               : "~2.5",
    "zendframework/zendservice-recaptcha"       : "2.*",
    "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module"              : "0.*",
    "zf-commons/zfc-base"                       : "0.*",
    "zf-commons/zfc-user"                       : "1.*",
    "zf-commons/zfc-user-doctrine-orm"          : "^1.0",
    "zf-commons/zfc-admin"                      : "0.1.0",
    "bjyoungblood/bjy-authorize"                : "1.*",
```

All works fine until I has updated project through composer...

```
Deprecated: ServiceManagerAwareInterface is deprecated and will be removed in version 3.0, along with the ServiceManagerAwareInitializer. Please update your class ZfcUser\Authentication\Storage\Db to remove the implementation, and start injecting your dependencies via factory instead. in /vagrant/personal/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Service/ServiceManagerConfig.php on line 127

Deprecated: ServiceManagerAwareInterface is deprecated and will be removed in version 3.0, along with the ServiceManagerAwareInitializer. Please update your class ZfcUser\Authentication\Adapter\Db to remove the implementation, and start injecting your dependencies via factory instead. in /vagrant/personal/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Service/ServiceManagerConfig.php on line 127

Deprecated: ServiceManagerAwareInterface is deprecated and will be removed in version 3.0, along with the ServiceManagerAwareInitializer. Please update your class ZfcUser\Service\User to remove the implementation, and start injecting your dependencies via factory instead. in /vagrant/personal/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Service/ServiceManagerConfig.php on line 127
```

I don't understand how It can correctly fix. I have no time, so I will be very grateful if someone will show in detail how this to change.

Comment: Stable and compatible with ZfcUser version is 2.5.2

Comment: We don't have time too.

Answer (score 0):

This issue needs some refactoring to the ZfcUser library. A [Github issue](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/issues/623) was already reported, also there is a possible, not yet merged, fix as [pull request](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/pull/627).

But you don't have to start crying, cause this is just an info. While you are using ZF2 ZfcUser will work as expected thanks to SemVer and not breaking backwards compatibility.